# PlayBack different voices

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I am working on iphone app, I required multiple voices , e.g. Adult voice become children voice.

How can i implement it, I am using AVFoundation for playing voice.

Plz provide some coded.

Comment: Could you be more specific - what exactly is it you're trying to do? If your question is about how to play a voice (or any sound, for that matter) using AVFoundation, I recommend you have a look at some examples on their website.
If what you're trying to do (if I understand your question correctly) to have an adult's voice become a child's voice, there are all sorts of ways you could try - most of which involve very complicated signal processing. But maybe you can get away with a simple cross-fade, in which case I recommend you look up possible cross-fade algorithms.

Comment: I am using AVFoundation framework, i have added play Audio  module, now i want to include say voice changer, change the voice of man into woman etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement what you need, you need pitch shifting capabilities. You can use OpenAL to achieve this.

Specifically, in OpenAL, to set pitch you do

```
alSourcef(source, AL_PITCH, 1.2f);
```

where source is the id of the OpenAL sound source.

If you are new to OpenAL, get started here: http://benbritten.com/2008/11/06/openal-sound-on-the-iphone/

Comment: thanks it did help me in learning openAL also, now the pitch value is from .5 to 2.0 i want the volume speed the same on every pitch value.(the speed at  which words are spoken be same on every pitch value)? how can i achieve this

Comment: @RanaAnees In order to maintain the speed you will need to apply time-stretching on the audio too. Unfortunaltely, OpenAL doesn't support time-stretching. You may have to look into any third party library such as DIRAC or SoundTouch.
http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac2-iphone/

Comment: can you provide me the links for the tutorial  of one of them which has sample code for playing audio on different pitches

Comment: @RanaAnees It's hard to find sample code for pitch-shifting with time-stretching. However I found this tutorial that solves your purpose just using AVFoundation:
http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/47